# Burninate [delphi64]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[delphi64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi64) was born for questions related to 64-bit Delphi compiler, but its name is misleading and difficult to find. Currently has 4 questions and 4 followers.

We are generally using tags like [delphi-xe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-xe), [delphi-xe7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-xe7) for specific product versions and this tag quite interfere this naming pattern. It's also an orphan since there is no [delphi32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi32) for 32-bit Delphi compiler related questions.

Finally, users can use generic [x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x64) (or similar) tags to mark their question being related to 64-bit compiler.

Comment: There are just 4 questions. No need for burniation, just retag the questions.

Comment: if the name is misleading but it has a use case, should it be renamed instead of removing?

Comment: @Christian, I wasn't sure about the process and wanted to make sure the community (and ideally contributors using Delphi tags) agrees with that.

Comment: @eis, that's why I would like to get some feedback. Though I'm inclined to burn it and replace with common [tag:64bit] tag. Grrr, there is **32-bit** and **64bit** (with no hyphen).

Comment: "Finally, users can use generic x64 (or similar) tags to mark their question being related to 64-bit compiler." Why!?

Comment: @Braiam, when they really want to point out their question is related to 64-bit platform by tag. It is already used for this purpose in some questions. Still, better than using delphi64, I'd say.

Comment: I would argue that [x64] or [x32] or any variant is not necessary for any question. I've seen plenty of times people trying to make sentences with the tags and this way of thinking is what keeps them. If you want to say that your platform is 32 or 64 bits, just saying in the question itself is enough, no need for a tag (and most likely, it barely has any relation with the problem they are trying to solve).

Comment: @Braiam is you look at the [tag usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/64bit), I'd argue for most of them it really is related. However, how it should be tagged... don't have a strong opinion on that. I can imagine someone being expert on, for example, converting software to work on 64-bit architecture.

Comment: Converting software to work on 64-bit architecture, right? What language? C? F? Python? See? You have a tag more useful than "I want something about X architecture", which people can be experts about, answer and follow.

Comment: @Braiam By that logic, instead of [string], we should instead have [java-string], [python-string], [lua-string], [php-string], etc. There is such a thing as being too specific.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo no, by my logic you should just be using java, python, lua, php, etc. There's such a thing that don't need 5 tags when you can use just 1 and reach the same amount of people.

Comment: @Braiam Except people who browse the [x64] tag will miss out on your question, and they may be familiar with common issues with porting software to x64. Additionally, there's no [c-64], [c++64], [d64], etc. tags.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo why there needs to be one?